# Error:(21, 8) error: class MyActivity is public - Can't edit MyActivity

Tags: java, android

When trying to edit MyActivity, it opens up MainActivity.java.

When trying to change the read only flag this error message shows up

> Failed to change read-only flag for /root/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/src/main/java/xyz/adamstephenson/android/myapplication/MainActivity.java

I'm trying to make a public class that outputs information when a button is pressed on Android.

The error is:

> Error:(21, 8) error: class MyActivity is public, should be declared in
>   a file named MyActivity.java

```
package xyz.adamstephenson.android.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

import static
xyz.adamstephenson.android.myapplication.R.layout.activity_main;


public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("button", "This is my message");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the name of the file ? The message is clear. Save this class under the name MyActivity.java file. It looks like currently you have it in the MainActivity.java but it is public.

Comment: You don't have a `public class MainActivity extends ...` in that code

Comment: The file name is MainActivity.Java with MainActivity inside it. [link](http://prntscr.com/btfj4w)

Comment: @cricket_007 Could you elaborate, what does do and what does it do?

Comment: If your file is named `X.java`, then you **must** have `public class X`... that is how you define a Java class. If you rename `X` to `Y`, as in `public class Y`, you **must rename the file** as well to `Y.java`

Comment: Thank you! It's now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when your `class file name` is not same as the class name inside the class file.

in drive you make a class

```
A.java 
but write it as 
public class A1{}
```

It will throw exception `: class A1 is public, should be declared in a file named A1.java`

How ever if you do something like following

```
A.java
and code it as 
class A1{}
```

Above will not throw any exception, but this class will not be accessible from outside the package.